# Jquery: change CLASS between multiple DIVs

Tags: jquery, css, function, class, html

I have such task: to create a function with jQuery which would change the CSS-class to the selected DIV. Class="XXX" can be repeated many times but Class="YYY" only once.

like this:

```
<div onclick="change_css()"class="xxx">text</div>
<div onclick="change_css()"class="xxx">text</div>
<div onclick="change_css()"class="xxx">text</div>
<div onclick="change_css()"class="yyy">text</div>
<div onclick="change_css()"class="xxx">text</div>
```

So, it means that Function need to find first where is class="yyy" and to change into class="xxx" and secondly to modify the class into "yyy" where it was activated by `onclick`...

please, help me to achieve this functions... I know that I need to use somehow `.addClass` and `.removeClass`

```
function change_css() {
/// some tricks here
}
```

thank you for every suggestion!

Comment: Can you show us the code that you have tried?

Comment: What about `$(".XXX").attr("class", "YYY")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest a different, more jQuery approach. Drop the "onclick" attributes from all `<div>`s and use another class (`myDiv` for this example) on all the relevant `<div>`s: **[Here's a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rDxzE/)**

```
<div class="myDiv xxx">text</div>
<div class="myDiv xxx">text</div>
<div class="myDiv xxx">text</div>
<div class="myDiv yyy">text</div>
<div class="myDiv xxx">text</div>
```

Then attach the click event using jQuery:

```
$(function(){

    $('.myDiv').click(function(){ // when a .myDiv is clicked
        $('.myDiv.yyy').removeClass('yyy').addClass('xxx'); // replace former yyy with xxx
        $(this).removeClass('xxx').addClass('yyy'); // add class yyy to current element instead of class xxx
    })

})
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!! Excelent support!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.xxx').on('click', function(){
    $('.xxx').removeClass('yyy');
    $(this).addClass('yyy');
});
```